# React native drawer (for iOS & Android) disable/drawerLock mode not working

Tags: react-native, drawer, navigator

I am new in React native development,I have completed drawer functionality using following tutorial and github example:-

- [Drawer Git hub link](https://github.com/caroaguilar/NavigationDrawerExample)
- [Drawer Tutorial link](http://caroaguilar.com/post/react-native-navigation-tutorial/)

So,According to above link `Drawer component` has one `disable` parameter which is helpful to lock drawer.

In my case,I have:-

- `Login Page :-` So I am trying to lock the drawer when user is not logged into system.
- `Home Page :-` So when ever user logged in successfully,I have open this page and unlock my drawer.

Added `render()` method for reference:-

```
render() {
      <Drawer
                ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
                disabled={!this.state.drawerEnabled}
                type="overlay"
                content={<Menu navigate={(route) => {
                    this._navigator.push(navigationHelper(route));
                    this._drawer.close()
                }}/>}
                tapToClose={true}
                openDrawerOffset={0.2}
                panCloseMask={0.2}
                closedDrawerOffset={-3}
                styles={{
                    drawer: {shadowColor: '#000000', shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 3},
                    main: {paddingLeft: 3}
                }}
                tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
                    main: { opacity:(2-ratio)/2 }
                })}>
                <Navigator
                    ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
                    configureScene={(route) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft}
                    initialRoute={{
                        id: 'Login',
                        title: 'Login',
                        index: 0
                    }}
                    renderScene={(route, navigator) => this._renderScene(route, navigator)}
                    navigationBar={
                        <Navigator.NavigationBar
                            style={styles.navBar}
                            routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
                    }
                />
            </Drawer>
      );
  }
```

So,My problem is:-

1. `disabled` parameter is not working.I have tried with `setState()' function also but the result is same.
2. Please suggest me other drawer examples/tutorials which works in above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [React Navigation library](https://reactnavigation.org/en/) is best option. Which is fully customizable and supported both Android and IOS. You should use [Drawer Navigator, can get documentation here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html)

Here I am adding code sample, that How I am locked/unlocked the drawer.

> Here StackApp will be your Stack Navigator which contain all the
>   drawer pages.

```
StackApp.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed'; //For child page it will lock drawer
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode
  };
};
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  StackHome: {screen: StackApp},
  // Auth: {screen: AuthScreen},
}
,{
  drawerWidth:width*0.8,
  contentComponent: (props) =>
    <ScrollView>
      <Menu {...props}/>
    </ScrollView>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check [react native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#props) and find '**drawerLockMode**'

Comment: But this drawerlayout works only in Android.I have to design the drawer which works on both iOS and Android.

Comment: your code here 'disabled={!this.state.drawerEnabled}', there is '!' mark, you didnt mistype ? just in case

Comment: `drawerEnabled` is the variable used during naivgation.which sets to true/false while switching between pages.I have also set this parameter directly to the `true` but gets same result